# Как правильно сделать запрос WHERE LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Доброго времени суток! Кто подскажет, никак не могу понять, бьюсь уже несколько дней, но не могу найти ответа. 
Есть запрос к бд:

```
 DataContext db = new DataContext(connectionString);

 Table<SearchWayTable> searchWayTables = db.GetTable<SearchWayTable>();
 var query = from u in db.GetTable<SearchWayTable>()
             select u;

 foreach(var u in query)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", u.FirstPoint, u.EndPoint, u.Distance);
 }

 Console.ReadLine();
```

И всё работает нормально, но если использую  WHERE при условии что данный город существует в базе данных то ничего не происходит

```
var query = from u in db.GetTable<SearchWayTable>()
            where u.FirstPoint == "Москва"
            select u;

[Table(Name = "SearchWayTable")]
class SearchWayTable 
{ 
   [Column]
   public string FirstPoint { get; set; }
   [Column]
   public string EndPoint { get; set; }
   [Column] 
   public double Distance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код класса `SearchWayTable` и покажите вывод первого фрагмента кода

Comment: [Table(Name = "SearchWayTable")]
    class SearchWayTable
    {
        [Column]
        public string FirstPoint { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string EndPoint { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public double Distance { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Москва Екатеринбург 1768
Москва Санкт-Петербург 709

Comment: вывод у вас именно с пробелами? У вас Console.WriteLine выводит без пробелов. Может нужно искать тогда "Москва " ;)

Comment: А если написать `where u.FirstPoint.Contains("Москва")`?

Comment: Большое спасибо! Contains как раз оказалось то что нужно, почему то я не делал так, хотя знал что есть такой вариант))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу проблему, то предположу что здесь:

```
var query = from u in db.GetTable<SearchWayTable>()
        where u.FirstPoint == "Москва"
        select u;
```

код возвращает IEnumerable.

Вам может помочь:

```
query.GetEnumerator().Current;
```

при условии, что Вы получаете один объект.

upd. Если вам нужен первый, с указанным параметром то:

```
var first = query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstPoint == "Москва")
```

upd. Если объектов группа(как я понял из Вашего комментария), не забудьте использовать .ToList(), что бы получить сформированный запрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Полезный ответ, не додумался)